# How to obtain a floating point value from a string?

Tags: c++, string

I am using `istringstream` from `<sstream>` header library to process the string, which works well for *integer* values but not for *floats*. The output I get are all integers for the below code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using std::istringstream;
using std::string;
using std::cout;

int main () 
{
    string a("1 2.0 3");

    istringstream my_stream(a);

    int n;
    float m, o;
    my_stream >> n >> m >> o;
    cout << n << "\n";
    cout << m << "\n";
    cout << o << "\n";
}
```

I want output of `m` to be `2.0`, but I am getting it as just integer `2`. Am I missing something here, or should I be using a something else?

Comment: Just specify your formatting parameters with the stream correctly.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the formatting. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Free clue: what happens when you set `float f=2.0;`, and then attempt to print it? You are not getting "just integer 2". You're getting the real deal. This has nothing to do, whatsoever, with `std::istringstream`.

Comment: @Deep - Change the `2.0` in your input string to be `2.1` and watch it work.

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't see that. Thank you for clarification @SamVarshavchik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here you go:](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45ddfa2f6f461501)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip> // << enable to control stream formatting

using std::istringstream;
using std::string;
using std::cout;

int main () 
{
    string a("1 2.0 3");

    istringstream my_stream(a);

    int n;
    float m, o;
    my_stream >> n >> m >> o;
    cout << std::fixed; // << One way to control how many digits are outputted
    cout << n << "\n";
    cout << m << "\n";
    cout << o << "\n";
}
```

Output

```
1
2.000000
3.000000
```

You can use more [stream formatting parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip) to control how many digits you want to see exactly.
You shouldn't confuse values and representation.